# Find $f(t)$ such that $ f\left(\dfrac{t^2}{2-t}\right) = -5t+4 $.

Tags: real-analysis

> Find $f(t)$ such that $ f\left(\dfrac{t^2}{2-t}\right) = -5t+4 $.

I don't really know how to approach this problem. Would you give any hint on how to start?

Comment: $f$ is defined in ???

Comment: $ f : \mathbb{R} \to \mathbb{R}$

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If $t=1$ you get $f(1)=-1,$ while if $t=-2$ you get $f(1)=14.$ So there is a problem...

There needs to be a restriction on $t$ to avoid such double values for $f$. For example $t\le 0$ or $0 \le t < 2$, or one of $2<t \le 4$ or $4 \le t$. See the graph of $t^2/(2-t).$

Answer (score 1):

Let $x=\frac{t^2}{2-t}$. Solving for $t$ gives $t=(-x \pm \sqrt{x(x+8)})/2$

It follows that $f(x) = -5t+4 = -5(-x \pm \sqrt{x(x+8)})/2+4$. The $\pm$ means that the function is not well defined by your expression, unless more information is provided.

Comment: The $x(x+8)$ under the radical here means this $f$ isn't defined on all of $\mathbb{R}$.

Comment: @coffeemath True. That too.

Answer (score 0):

Hint: $\frac{t^2}{2-t} = y \Leftrightarrow t^2 + y t - 2 y = 0 $, use the 2nd degree formula to express t in function of y, $x(y)$, then you get $f ( y ) = - 5 x(y) +4$.